# Listening for Automatically-Triggered Client Events with page.on('customEvent', fn)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/5693546) seems to cover what I want to do, but it appears to be a thought experiment, rather than working code.  In any case, I'm having trouble getting it to work for me.

I'm opening a page in PhantomJs that loads a JavaScript library and starts a process. When the process completes, that library triggers an event within the context of the instance object. I'd like to either

(a) set up PhantomJS to listen for the right event in the instance object in the client page

OR

(b) add some code to the client page that "bubbles-up" the event to `window` and set up PhantomJS to listen for that.

Here's what I've tried for option B.

client.html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src='https://example.com/library.js'></script>
  <script>
    function sendWindowEvent() {
      // I've also tried document, top.parent, etc.
      window.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('myEvent', {
        detail: {
          message: "Hello World!",
          time: new Date(),
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      }));
    }

    var instance = new myLibrary.constructor();
    instance.addEventListener("onInitialized", sendWindowEvent);
    instance.start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In node.js app:

```
const headlessBrowser = await phantom.create();
const page = await headlessBrowser.createPage();
await page.on('onResourceRequested', (requestData) => {
  console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);  // displays http://localhost:1337/client.html & https://example.com/library.js
});
await page.on('myEvent', async (evt) => {
  console.log('event detected:', evt);  // never triggered
});
const openStatus = await page.open('http://localhost:1337/client.html');
console.log('phantom status:', openStatus);  // displays true
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?  Is this not a supported feature?  *Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1):

`page.on` event listeners are responding to specific technical events generated by PhantomJS, not by its target page. To receive native page events you will have to subscribe to them in the browser context:

```
await page.evaluate(function(){
    window.addEventListener("myEvent", function(e){ console.log(e)})
});
```

Be sure to subscribe to [page.onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) callback to get that message.

Comment: That's a shame, but onConsoleMessage is better than nothing.  Thanks!

Comment: Am I misunderstanding what's going on in the gist, then?  Or was I correct that it's just a thought experiment for potential future features? https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/5693546

Comment: For anyone else, in the future, `page.onConsoleMessage()` didn't work for me (using the phantom module, instead of webpage), but `page.on('onConsoleMessage', msg => console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg));` did.

Comment: Wait, it seems like `window.callPhantom(msg)` and `page.on('onCallback', cb)` do exactly what I need. I just missed them before...

Comment: `page.onConsoleMessage() didn't work for me` of course it wouldn't as it's raw PhantomJS but you converted it correctly to `page.on('onConsoleMessage')`. Sorry, I didn't have time today to check it with the phantom package so just left as recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

`window.callPhantom()` was what I was looking for.  Documentation is [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html).

client.html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src='https://example.com/library.js'></script>
  <script>
    function sendWindowEvent() {
      if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
        window.callPhantom({hello: 'world'});
      }
    }

    var instance = new myLibrary.constructor();
    instance.addEventListener("onInitialized", sendWindowEvent);
    instance.start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In node.js app:

```
const headlessBrowser = await phantom.create();
const page = await headlessBrowser.createPage();
page.on('onCallback', data => {
  console.log('CALLBACK: ' + JSON.stringify(data)); // Prints 'CALLBACK: {"hello":"world"}'
});
page.open('http://localhost:1337/client.html');
```